# Nested IF formulas for a simple logic field on the opportunity

Tags: formula, nested, if

Can you please cast your eyes at my formula and spot the mistake? I've been trying to crack this but to no avail. Looked through example nested formulas and this forum as well... I know I'm just glancing over something tiny and you guys will spot it in an instant!

Error message:

```
Error: Syntax error. Extra ')'
```

Syntax:

```
IF(
   AND(
      Department_MQL__c <> 'SDR generated, relationship management', 
      Department_SQL__c = 'SDR',
      ISPICKVAL(Account.Sector__c, '<>Supplier/Distributor')),
         "Marketing",

IF(
   AND(
      ISPICKVAL(Account.Sector__c, '<>Supplier/Distributor'),
      Department_MQL__c <> 'SDR generated, digital team',
      Department_SQL__c = 'relationship management')),
         "Customer Success",

IF(
   AND(
      ISPICKVAL(Account.Sector__c, '<>Supplier/Distributor'),
      Department_SQL__c = 'sales')),
         "Sales",

            NULL)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(
   AND(
      Department_MQL__c <> 'SDR generated, relationship management', 
      Department_SQL__c = 'SDR',
      ISPICKVAL(Account.Sector__c, '<>Supplier/Distributor')),
         "Marketing",

IF(
   AND(
      ISPICKVAL(Account.Sector__c, '<>Supplier/Distributor'),
      Department_MQL__c <> 'SDR generated, digital team',
      Department_SQL__c = 'relationship management'),
         "Customer Success",

IF(
   AND(
      ISPICKVAL(Account.Sector__c, '<>Supplier/Distributor'),
      Department_SQL__c = 'sales'),
         "Sales",

            NULL)))
```